# JGit occasionally staging all files for deletion

Tags: git, jgit

I have a wrapper around Git that's designed to commit and push single files at a time. There's an intermittent issue where, instead of committing a single file, all of the files in the repo are staged for deletion, and that is pushed to the server.

This operation is called via a webservice, so I initially suspected some sort of race condition, but I've `synchronized` the method that does the commit and it still happens on occasion.

The add code is

```
  for (RepoFile file : commit.getFiles())
  {

    final String gitFilePattern = getGitFilePattern(file.getFileName());
    LOG.info("Adding file pattern: " + gitFilePattern);
    git.add().addFilepattern(gitFilePattern).call();
  }
```

The commit code is

```java
RevCommit call = git.commit().setMessage(comment).setAuthor(name, email).call();
String commitId = call.getId().name();

PushCommand push = git.push();
push.setTransportConfigCallback(SSHTransportProducer.produce(PropertiesService.getProperty("SSH_PASSPHRASE"), PropertiesService.getProperty("SSH_KEY")));
push.call();
```

Any ideas of what could be causing this?

Comment: Your code snippet is missing the add/remove-from-index part. `git.commit()...call()` creates a commit from whatever the index currently contains.

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann Sorry, I'll include that - this is a very intermittent issue, like one in thirty commits.

Comment: What does `getGitFilePattern()` return?

Comment: The exact file path to the file being committed.

Comment: I can't imagine why all files would be staged for deletion, unless someone explicitly uses the `RmCommand`. Any chance your code does that? You may want to reset the index before adding files to ensure only the immediate changes to the index take effect.

Comment: My code has no usages of any sort of deletion at all - it just adds and modifies. No one else touches the server it's running on either. It's very strange.

Comment: Does the problem vanish of you reset the index (`git.reset().setMode(ResetType.MIXED).call()`) before adding and committing?

Comment: Your example does not describe how files are manipulated in the work tree—how are they created/appended/moved/deleted. Without this information, it's hard to know what's happening in Git. And the code block "add code" is questionable: you're retrieving all the files from a commit. Where does the "commit" come from, why are you adding everything again from an existing commit, and what those files means: are they created or deleted?